# How to get the parameter of text outside the html page in CN1

Tags: codenameone

Pls how can I get the value of text supplied in html page outside the html, for example java code to get the parameter of text in html that says

```
  String SURNAME = request.getParameter("SURNAME_TXT");
```

pls how can I get this in CN1

Comment: That's usually something you do in the server not in the client. You are not in an HTML page when you are running an app so I don't quite understand what is being asked.

Comment: If I want to get the values in a text box in HTML page. How can I reference to the variable name of the text box. For example <input type = "text" name = "textbox1" value = "This is text box"  />

Comment: . If I want to get the value of textbox1 outside the Browser Component on the same page. Pls how can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access values from HTML you will need to use the JavaScript bridge to inject code into the web page. This isn't trivial and discussed further [here](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html).